# View on the link returning cached data

Tags: c#, angularjs, caching

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
$http.get("/Planning/GetAllPlanningOrdersInfo", { params: { filter: $scope.filteredUrl } })
                .success(function (data) {
                    if (JSON.stringify(data).indexOf('Error: ') > 0)
                    {
                        dial.messages.error(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.orders = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                })
                .error(function (error)
                {
                    reportFriendlyAjaxError(error);
                })
                .finally(function ()
                {
                    $scope.tableLoading = false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });

</script>
```

I have a view written in c# which is accessed by click on the link. The view returns data from an OData service and AngularJS is used for page modification like selecting checkboxes and radio buttons.
But when the page is accessed by clicking the link it gives cached data.

How to remove the caching?  To get data, am using $http.get in angularjs?

Comment: You can use `cache:false` property of `$http` service. For more clear answer please share your code

Comment: added the code which gets the data from the API, this did not return latest data until I refresh the page using browser refresh.